# Reformating the URL's generated by the routing system

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have been trying to solve a problem for quite a while that it is related to routing and links with no luck.

I have an application that stores a number of books. Each book has links that displays it's details. In order to get the details I am using the ID for each book in my link. This is the code for the link:

```
@Html.ActionLink(book.Name, "Details", new { bookId = book.Id , book = book.BookUrl })
```

When the user clicks one of the links this is the controller that is being called and I am not allowed to modify it:

```
 public ActionResult Details (int bookId){..}
```

And this is how my link will be displayed:

```
http://localhost:51208/Home/Details/C-sharp-5.0-in-a-Nutshell-The-Definitive-Reference/BookId-2
```

What I would like is someway to stop displaying the controler action and BookId.So my link would look something like this:

```
http://localhost:51208/C-sharp-5.0-in-a-Nutshell-The-Definitive-Reference
```

From what I can tell so far there is no way to do this using the standard functionality of routing so I figured I have to extend it's functionality somehow.

I have been reading about this in [PRO ASP.NET MVC 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242361) and from what I have read I have to create a class and inherit from `RouteBase`.

This will result in having to implement two methods one is `RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)` and the other `VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)`

So far I only understand that `GetVirtualPath` is responsible for generating the links so I figure this is where I would have to create the implementation to get the functionality I desire.

If this is the case can someone give me an idea on how I should implement this method?

If this is not the route to take then how can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by implementing your own version of RouteBase.  You would need to implement both `GetRouteData` and `GetVirtualPath`.

Your implementation of `GetRouteData` would need to check your database of books to see if the URL contains the name of a book in your database, and then return the correct route data e.g.

```
public class BookRoute : RouteBase
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var url = httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
        url = url.Replace(@"~/", "");

        var book = getBookWithTheNameThatMatchesTheUrl(url);

        if (book != null)
        {
            var rd = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
            rd.Values.Add("controller", "Home");
            rd.Values.Add("action", "Details");
            rd.Values.Add("bookId", book.Id);
            return rd;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

and your implementation of `GetVirtualPath` would need to do the opposite - find the name of the book with the given ID, and return the appropriate URL.

e.g.

```
public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, 
                                               RouteValueDictionary values)
{
    if ((string)values["action"] == "Details" && 
        (string)values["controller"] == "Home")
    {
        var bookId = (int)values["bookId"];
        var bookName = LookUpTheBookNameForTheBookWithThisId(bookId);
        return new VirtualPathData(this, bookName);    
    }

    return null;
}
```

Lastly, add `routes.Add(new BookRoute());` where you are registering the routes to enable this new route to be checked.

Given that the method `getBookWithTheNameThatMatchesTheUrl()` would hit the database for every page, you'd want to be caching the look-ups.

Answer (score 2):

You can put an extra route in your `RouteConfig.cs` as below:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Book Details", // Route name
        "{ bookName }", // URL with parameters
             new { controller = "BookController",
                   action = "Details", 
                   name = UrlParameter.Optional
                 } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Change your `Details` method accordingly, but its parameter must be `bookName`.

**Note :**

Put this route at the bottom of all routes you have defined for avoiding ambiguity.

Comment: this can not be done I am not allowed to modify the controller in any way but this helped me in removing the controller and action in the url I still have to find away to not display the id

Comment: then you can only put the `bookId` in your path and not the `bookName`.

Comment: @aleczandru Then how do you suppose you will know `int bookId` without supplying it in the url???

Comment: It's pretty obvious you can get it from the `bookName`...from the database may be...

Comment: well that I do not know yet my senior developer said it is posible without modifing the controller

Comment: @aleczandru So he might think using c# code on view page..that is allowed but not a good practice..

Comment: @aleczandru, then I'd be interested to see what the senior developer would come with as a solution. ;)